# Air for ios, language list on itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, air, itunes

i am looking for a way to set the available language list on itunes for my ios app. I came across this workarround http://forums.adobe.com/thread/863281.

Wondering maybe if the issue was fixed on more recent air sdks or if someone used a more straightforward method.    Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On air 3.5 and perhaps on earlier versions you can use

```
<supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>
```

Answer (score 0):

No sure if it works yet, but I've been using this style in my *-app.xml. Currently I'm having build issues with this in FB 4.6

```
    <name>
    <text xml:lang="ar">المذيع برو</text>
    <text xml:lang="en">BroadcasterPro</text>
    <text xml:lang="de">Broadcaster Pro</text>
    <text xml:lang="es">Locutor Pro</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">Diffuseur Pro</text>
    <text xml:lang="ja">放送局のプロ</text>
    <text xml:lang="ko">방송 프로</text>
    <text xml:lang="pl">Pro Broadcaster</text>
    <text xml:lang="pt">Pro Broadcaster</text>
    <text xml:lang="ru">Транслятор Pro</text>
    <text xml:lang="zh">播放臨</text>  
</name>

<supportedLanguages>ar en de es fr ja ko pl pt ru zh</supportedLanguages>
```